# Draytek Vigor 2925 outgoing connection

Tags: firewall, security

I have a Draytek Vigor 2925 at home. I use it for my home network an especially the VLAN option is nice, because I need to have multiple "seperate" networks.

I have a strange problem, I'm not able to use Google Play on my Phone and my LG TV cannot connect with Youtube, Netflix and it's own app center.

I have replaced the Draytek router with a very cheap TP-Link TL-WR841N router and then all the connections do work. So there is a problem with my Draytek Vigor 2925 configuration, I assume it's blocking one or more outgoing ports. I found out that Android is using the ports 5228 and 5222.
I have tried almost everything, including
Accepted large incoming fragmented UDP or ICMP packets  in the firewall.
Disabled Strict Security Firewall

Does anyone recognize this problem? What should I do or try to fix this?

Many thanks!

Comment: This really isn't the appropriate forum for this question since it is about home networking. The manufacturer has support via e-mail at https://www.draytek.com/index.php?option=com_jumi&view=application&fileid=20&Itemid=592&lang=en

Comment: Can you draw a small diagram of what your network looks like?

Comment: This should have been close as off-topic before it had any answers, but we (the community) were slow, and now it has a bounty. With a bounty, we can no longer on-hold/close vote, AND we (the mods) cannot migrate it to Super User. I believe [this is a bug](http://meta.networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/488/unexpected-close-bounty-interaction).

Answer (score 1):

This is likely because of NAT or PAT or security.  The [Vigor](https://www.draytek.com/index.php?option=com_k2&view=item&id=5247:vigor2925&Itemid=660&lang=en) is a type of security appliance with no WiFi AP functionality.  The [TPLink](http://www.tp-link.com/lk/products/details/?model=TL-WR841N#fea) is a WiFi AP with some security features.  Try and see what IP address your endpoints are getting when using these two different gateways.  Log into the Vigor and try and tweak the security config to allow required ports/communication.

I noticed the TPLink allows for a 'DMZ host' which is allows a host to virtually sit outside with a public IP.

Why not just use the TP-Link and be done?

Comment: Because the Draytek Vigor is used as a modem as well. There is only one WAN cable and that is in the Draytek.  I have already tried to tweak security config under NAT -> Port Triggering. See http://www.draytek.com/index.php?lang=en&Itemid=302 for an admin demo.